# Microsoft Bot Framework: HTTP status code InternalServerError

Tags: botframework

I have a couple of bots which were working without any issues till today morning. I was given the following warning message on the bot portal:

`We've revised our security protocol. Update to Bot Builder 3.5+ or compatible security configuration by July 31, 2017 to keep your bot working.`

So I upgraded the botbuilder framework to `3.8.3` using `npm install –save botbuilder`

Ever since I upgraded one bot stopped working but the other works fine. The error message I get is `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError`. The bot works perfectly fine on the bot emulator but not after it's deployed to azure. So it's not even a code issue.  To think if it's a Microsoft server issue, my other bot works just fine. What could be possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and my bot is back up again running now. Apparently its some deployment issues.

I've run the following command first:

> azure site log tail *botsitename*

I got an error message saying:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module './dialogs/Prompt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\logger.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

So, I've deleted the `node_modules` folder in the root and reinstalled `npm`. That brought my bot back to life! :)